# Warnings running a Maven project (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

**I have the following warnings when I run Maven project with goals of jetty:run for Spring MVC like below:**

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@7dd712e8{/dfaMusicStore,C:\Users\Tony Do\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\dfaMusicStore\src\main\webapp}
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:375)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1035)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations(Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(AbstractConfiguration.java:119)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebApp(AbstractConfiguration.java:96)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Configuration.java:124)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1217)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:371)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:307)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

[WARNING] Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@7dd712e8{/dfaMusicStore,C:\Users\Tony Do\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\dfaMusicStore\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:375)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1035)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations(Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(AbstractConfiguration.java:119)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebApp(AbstractConfiguration.java:96)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Configuration.java:124)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1217)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo$1.filesChanged(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:409)
at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.reportBulkChanges(Scanner.java:493)
at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:359)
at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:286)
at org.mortbay.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:246)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

**Below is my 'pom.xml' file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springMvcDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvcDemo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>mvcDemo Maven Webapp</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for package 'org.springframework.stereotype' -->               
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for package 'org.springframework.ui' -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for package 'org.springframework.web.bind.annotation' -->  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>     
   </dependencies>
   <build>
     <finalName>mvcDemo</finalName>

     <plugins>
     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- Update classpath with an Eclipse User Library via Maven Eclipse Plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <classpathContainers>       
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>        
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Maven MVC</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Spring MVC</classpathContainer>
        </classpathContainers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-javaagent C:/Users/7d0/Desktop/Eclipse/Spring MVC Demo/JAR Files/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar</argLine>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>                 
                <argLine>-javaagent C:/Users/7d0/Desktop/Eclipse/Spring MVC Demo/JAR Files/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar</argLine>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>                                                        
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>    
  </build>
</project>
```

**I have included the following JAR files in 'Maven MVC' library:**

```
jetty-6.1.26.jar, 
jetty-plus-6.1.26.jar, 
maven-hudson-plugin-6.1.7.jar, 
org.mortbay.jetty.util.jar, 
plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar
```

**The following JAR files in 'Spring MVC' library:**

```
classmate-1.0.0.jar, 
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, 
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, 
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, 
commons-logging-1.2.jar, 

All .jar files in spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE/libs/ folder 
(spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, ...)
```

**How can I fix these warning to run the Maven project for Spring MVC? Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the above dependency use this plugin for jetty, leave out the configuration till you get it to work first

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.1.v20140108</version>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add javax.servlet-api dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still receive warning when I run the Maven project. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing that seems odd, is that you seem to be mixing Spring 2.5 with Spring 3 components. This will almost certainly cause an endless supply of headaches and unpredictable behavior. Pick a version of spring and stick to it.

Try removing the dependency on spring 2.5.6.

Also, why I don't think this is necessarily part of the problem, upgrading to a non-depreciated version of jetty as others have suggested, is almost certainly a good idea. You are four significant versions behind.